# How to wait for result of Scala Futures in for comprehension

Tags: scala, for-loop, for-comprehension

I am having a issue with the below piece of code. I want 'combine' method to get triggered after all groundCoffee,heaterWater,frothedMilk method completes. They would be triggered concurrently.All the 4 methods grind,heatWater,frothMilk,brew are concurrently executed using a future.

```
def prepareCappuccino(): Future[Cappuccino] = {
  val groundCoffee = grind("arabica beans")
  val heatedWater = heatWater(Water(20))
  val frothedMilk = frothMilk("milk")
  for {
    ground <- groundCoffee
    water <- heatedWater
    foam <- frothedMilk
    espresso <- brew(ground, water)
  } yield combine(espresso, foam)
}
```

When I execute the above method the output I am getting is below

```
start grinding...
heating the water now
milk frothing system engaged!
```

And the program exits after this. I got this example from a site while I was trying to learn futures. How can the program be made to wait so that combine method get triggered after all the futures return?

Comment: Thanks @om-nom-nom for helping out with formatting

Comment: You can just type Thread.sleep(_duration_) or use Await from scala.concurrent package

Comment: yes I can do that.When I use a breakpoint the program completes as expected. But that is not what i want. Is there any other way to do this where the execution of combine method happens without the program exiting? Hope I am not confusing too much

Comment: I just gave you the solution.

`import scala.concurrent.duration._
scala.concurrent.Await.ready(prepareCappuccino, 5.seconds)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Await here:

```
val f = Future.sequence(futures.toList)
Await.ready(f, Duration.Inf)
```

I assume, you have all the futures packed in a list. The Await.ready makes all the waiting work.

Comment: I did it and it worked. But the onSuccess function of the individual futures is not getting triggered. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @mavrav, if you use `map` instead of `onSuccess` and `Await` resulting future, you'll get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The solution already posted to `Await` for a future is a solution when you want to deliberately block execution on that thread. Two common reasons to do this are for testing, when you want to wait for the outcome before making an assertion, and when otherwise all threads would exit (as is the case when doing toy examples).

However in a proper long lived application `Await` is generally to be avoided.

Your question already contains one of the correct ways to do future composition - using a for comprehension. Bear in mind here, that for-comprehensions are converted to flatMaps, maps and withFilter operations, so any futures you invoke in the for-comprehension will only be created after the others complete, ie serially.

If you want a bunch of futures to operate in concurrently, then you would create them before entering the for-comprehension as you have done.

Comment: Thats right @monkjack. But when I try to run the example combine method never gets called which is not what I want. Actually i am simulating this to match a cache loading system during server startup where the caches should be loaded concurrently so as to save time.So if a incoming thread comes while the cache is getting loaded, it should wait till the cache objects get loaded. So I feel Await.ready is good method to implement that. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The situation you are running into is probably because your program is exiting. As for a good solution to your problem which is one of delaying requests until a state is reached, post up another question with specific details.